# How to fail in a squat-rack

Tags: squats

At my gym we have a squat-rack similar to this one:

[image: Squat Rack Photo]

I can lower myself if I fail a squat, and the bar ends up on the bars on the side. But I wonder what to do if I lose my balance and stumble either forwards or backwards. Normally I'm standing rotated 180 versus the dude in the picture btw. Do I need a spotter, or can I just safely train in this rack somehow?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't get up, you toss the weight behind you, and step forward. If the handles don't catch it, they were too short anyway. In fact, the ones in the picture don't look very long at all.

Again, whether there are handles in place or not, dump it and step forward.

Here's a video of this exact problem being explained and demonstrated: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlPE49zlez4

Comment: But in that video he says it applies to when you're squatting heavy "outside of a rack", which is not what I'm doing. Why shouldn't I then use the technique in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJ6SsRsOll8

Comment: They're the same technique. In your video, he simply holds onto the bar for longer, because he knows he has the safety bars in place.